# How to access both webcams mediastream in chrome browser simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, html, webcam, mediastream

I want to access both webcams in chrome browser simultaneously. My laptop has two webcams and I want to show both of them in a html page. This code shows only one webcam (back webcam) and I can't change it to use front webcam (Consider that, I know if I change chrome privacy, I can use only the other webcam). but the question is how can I use both of them ***simultaneously***?
This is the code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Camera Test</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div style="width:400px; background:#ccc; border:10px solid #ddd; margin:0 auto;">
            
            <video id="video" width="400" height="300" autoplay></video>
    
        </div>
        <script>

        (function () {

            var video = document.getElementById('video');

            navigator.getMedia =  navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                  navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                                  navigator.msGetUserMedia;
                          
            //Capture video
            navigator.getMedia({
                video: true,
                audio: false
            }, function (stream) {
                console.log(stream);
            
                var mediaStream = new MediaStream(stream);
                video.srcObject = mediaStream;
                video.play();

            }, function (error) {
                console.error('MediaStream error:', error);
            });

        })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't you stream them in two iframes on the same page?

Comment: @Michel yes I can use two iframes.  but the question is how can I access both? I can't choose any cameras. I have only one choice. How to access the other webcam?

Comment: @Michel yes I can use two iframes.  but the question is how can I access both? I can't choose any cameras. I have only one choice. How to access the other webcam?